# ignoring hidden rows

Tags: javascript, jquery

How would I rewrite this function so that any hidden rows are completely ignored?

```
function stripeRows(table) {
    var numRows = table.rows.length;
    for (var i = 1; i < numRows; i++) {
        var ID = table.rows[i].id;
        if (i % 2 == 0) {
            table.rows[i].className = "GridRow";
        }
        else {
            table.rows[i].className = "GridRowAlt";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you hide your rows? CSS? You could then test for the appropriate style setting.

Comment: i am hiding my rows in another function with $("#row").hide();

Comment: Since you are hiding it with javascript, set the row styles for alternating classes with a selector. Removed my answer as i thought you where hiding it serverside.

Comment: do accept answer if it works for you

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT**: turns out my suggestion to use CSS will not work - go figure... In any case you can use jQuery

```
$('tr:visible:odd').addClass('even');
$('tr:visible:even').addClass('odd');
```

(note the inversion, since jQuery counts from 0). No need to loop at all! :-)

[See it working](http://jsfiddle.net/FUkYQ/)

Comment: Would this also ignore hidden rows?

Comment: I'm almost sure yes, but I have not checked.

Comment: Does this not need to go within a loop so that I can reference my table object?

Comment: Let me assume that your table has an id, say `tableId`. You only need to change `$('tr:visible:odd')` to `$('#tableId tr:visible:odd')`. Again, there is no need to manually loop through the elements, or to make a separate function. If you don't get your table by id, you only need to make a small adjustment (which depends on the way you get your table).

Answer (score 0):

However you detect hidden rows, you must at least decouple your counter from your row index, e.g. via [`for(... in ...)`](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_loop_for_in.asp). If you find a hidden row, continue your loop:

```
var i = 0;
for (var row in table.rows) {
    if(row.style.visibility == 'hidden') 
    // or similar (see other answers), e.g.: if($('#element_id:visible').length > 0) 
        continue;

    var ID = row.id;
    if (i % 2 == 0) {
        row.className = "GridRow";
    }
    else {
        row.className = "GridRowAlt";
    }
    ++i;
}
```

Comment: It's only an example code, because my point is not how to detect a hidden row (see Andrea's answer for that), but how you would have to change your for loop to get this to work. Hope I was able to help!